# Trying to make associations with Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

i'm learning Rails and i'm doing an exercise to practice associations and migration files.

Currently, trying to make a models between users, auction item, and bids.

So far for the migrate files I have the following:

```
    class CreateItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :auction do |t|
            t.string :item_name
            t.string :condition
            t.date :start_date
            t.date :end_date
            t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


 class CreateBids < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bids do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :auction_id

      t.timestamps
    end
 end
end


   class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

end

These are the following models:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bidder, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "bidder_id"
  belongs_to :auction
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids
  has_many :auctions, :foreign_key => 'bidder_id'

  has_secure_password
end


class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :bids
  has_many :bidders, through: :bids
end
```

Any suggestions or opinions? I'm currently trying to test the tables but auctions doesn't seem to be working...
Specifically, my auction table can't seem to find a user_id and therefore a user doesn't have any auctions.

Comment: What does `auction` have? Where is `bidder_id`? Shouldn't that be `user_id`?

Comment: Yeah, I just removed the `bidder_id` and replaced it with 'user_id' and it seems to be working now, just hoping the rest is fine.

Comment: Posted the answer to wrap it up..and you can search/post another question if something else breaks..

Comment: I don't see a `user_id` in `Auction` so `seller` is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

`foreign_key` refers to the `_id` (by default) or any unique attribute used to associate the models.

I can't see `bidder` model, you need to replace them with `user_id` as they are associated to `user` model.

Refer for more details [`belongs_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateBids < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bids do |t|
      t.integer :user_id **do not think this is correct** 
      t.integer :auction_id **or this one** 

      t.timestamps
    end
 end
end
```

You want to use something more along the lines of the following

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.integer :total_time
      t.references :version, foreign_key: true **#this is how a foreign key should be declared**
      t.integer :total_points

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to change things in future migrations you can always add a reference:

```
  def change
    add_reference :levels, :version, foreign_key: true
  end
```